# Why does this give syntax error under TypeError?

Tags: ocaml

```
let n1 = eval_expr e1 in
let n2 = eval_expr e2 in
(match n1, n2 with
 | Int_Val i, Int_Val j -> Int_Val i, Int_Val j
 | _ -> raise TypeError) in

let n3 = (n1 + n2) in
n3
```

It says syntax error under TypeError, why?

Answer (score 2):

(If possible you should provide the full error message and show the associated position in the text.)

The error is actually located on the symbol `in` on the following line:

```
| _ -> raise TypeError) in
```

In fact at that point there is no `let` for the `in` to be associated wtih. You have had two `let`s and two `in`s before that.

It seems to me that you're trying to extract the integer values `i` and `j`. You can do that something like this:

```
let i, j =
    match n1, n2 with
    | Int_val i, Int_val j -> i, j
    | _ -> raise TypeError
in
i + j
```

Your code applies `+` to `n1` and `n2`, which doesn't make sense since they appear to be values of some algebraic type (not int).

Comment: It may be worth noting that in the code sample you provide, there is no practical purpose to the let binding, as opposed to just: `match n1, n2 with Int_val i, Int_val j -> i + j | _ -> raise TypeError`. One might also express this as a let binding with a capture and rethrow on `Match_failure`. `try let (Int_val i, Int_val j) = (n1, n2) in i + j with Match_failure _ -> raise TypeError`.